# HIVEQL - SQL Syntax/Function assistance

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the below query which works fine in SQL SERVER 
But i am trying to use it in HADOOP/HIVEQL.

However HIVEQL does not have the Top 1 function or the outer apply.
Can anyone assist with an alternative but the same result?

Below is the data (table) and under it are the results I am trying to achieve.

Thanks,
Danii

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
ID varchar(20)NOT NULL
,CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,CompletedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,TYPES varchar(20) NOT NULL
,STATUSS varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('61030203647','20160427','20160427','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160425','20160426','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160422','20160422','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20170311','20170613','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160731','20160805','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160801','20160805','Re-Activattion','PARTIALLY');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160809','20160809','Re-Activattion','PARTIALLY');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160810','20160810','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160810','20160810','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160811','20160811','Re-Activattion','COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160812','20160814','Re-Activattion','N-CO');

;WITH src AS (
SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CompletedDate, TYPES, STATUSS,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate , CompletedDate) AS rn
 FROM #temp 
)

,grouped as (
Select s.* ,d.rnGrp from src s
outer apply (select top 1 rn rnGrp from src s2 
where s.ID=s2.ID and s2.STATUSS='COMP' and s2.rn>=s.rn ) d(rnGrp))

,grouped1 as ( 
Select ID, min(CreatedDate) CreatedDate,  max(CompletedDate) CompletedDate
,rnGrp,
Case when SUM(CASE WHEN STATUSS = 'COMP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >0 then 
Case when TYPES='De-Activattion' then 'NOT A RE-ACT' else
CAST( DATEDIFF(day,min(CreatedDate) ,max(CompletedDate)  )  AS VARCHAR(25))
END
ELSE 'NOT COMPLETED' END AS ACT_COMPLETION_TIME 

,Sum(CASE WHEN STATUSS = 'N-CO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [ACT NCO #]

From grouped 
Group by ID, rnGrp,TYPES
)
,grouped2 as (
select  ID, CreatedDate,    CompletedDate,   ACT_COMPLETION_TIME,   [ACT NCO #]

  ,Count(*) Over(Partition by ID) cnt
  ,row_number()Over(Partition by ID Order by CreatedDate) rn 
 from grouped1
 )

 Select g2.ID,
 Stuff(Convert(varchar(11),g2.CreatedDate,100),4,4,'-') as MIN_CREATED_MONTH_YEAR
 ,g2.ACT_COMPLETION_TIME,   g2.[ACT NCO #]

 from grouped2 g2 
 left join grouped2 g3 on g2.ID=g3.ID and g2.rn=g3.rn+1
```

---

WANT

```
 CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
 ID varchar(20) NOT NULL
,MIN_CREATED_MONTH_YEAR  varchar(20)
,ACT_COMPLETION_TIME varchar(20)
,ACT_NCO varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO #temp2
VALUES ('61030203647','Apr-2016','5','2');
INSERT INTO #temp2
VALUES ('61030203647','Mar-2017','94','0');
INSERT INTO #temp2
VALUES ('64074558792','Jul-2016','11','3');

SELECT *
FROM #temp2
```

I am trying to add a 2 week tolerance to grouping IDs within 2 weeks.
The attached query does what it needs to and i know how to add the 2 weeks tolerance at the end (which I have not included here not to convoluted things)

My explanation is below, basically all i need really is the outer apply and the top 1 written in Hiveql because those functions dont exist.

Explanation:
61030203647 Re-Act requests were created in 2016 and then in 2017 (past 2 weeks so they can be considered as 2 separate issues raised (should be 5 days (min created date) to 27th (max completed date))

However 64074558792, completed on the 11.08 and created on the 31.07 THEN another Re-Act was created on the 12. This can be a mistake, this is within 2 weeks tolerance, if its within 2 weeks of the completion date treat them as the same issue (unlike the example above which was past 2 weeks and was separated as 2 requests.)

Comment: Are you trying to use `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: **(1)** add the table DLL **(2)** there is a good chance you are doing it wrong in the first place. Add a **reasonable** data sample (2 rows won't do the trick), including requested results

Comment: Hi @DuduMarkovitz have provided additonal information see above. Hope this helps. IF you are able to provide me some input to achieve that desired result in HIVE you are a miracle worker!

Comment: For many rows insertion better use single insert statement with select UNION ALL select ... . It will perform faster.